# Multiple If Else in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to write a formula in excel. I want to implement below in excel

```
if(C10 != "SA")
{
    if(H10 == L1 OR H10 == L2)
    {
        if(I10 != "A")
        {
            ERROR
        }
        else
        {
            if(J10 == "2")
            {
                Concate
            }
            else
            {
                ERROR
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ERROR
    }   
}
else
{
    ERROR   
}
```

And I write below formula in excel

```
=if(NOT c10 = "SA",if(h10 = "L1" OR h10 = "L2",if(NOT i10 = "A","ERROR!",if(j10 = "2","ERROR!",CONCAT(c10:k10))),"ERROR!"),"ERROR!")
```

But it gives me error when I enter a formula

[image]

Please help me to solve the issue. Advance thanks

Comment: This is not the valid way how to use NOT and OR as those are "functions()" ... Go read over it again

Comment: Thanks for correction. Can you please give some hint.

Comment: If I want to implemet != ad || in excel how I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OR syntax is `... OR(<condition1>, <condition2>)` and NOT is `...NOT(<condition1>)...`. Try,

```
=if(NOT(c10="SA"), if(OR(h10="L1", h10="L2"), if(NOT(i10 = "A"), "ERROR!", if(j10 = "2", "ERROR!", CONCAT(c10:k10))), "ERROR!"), "ERROR!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt at your formula:

```
IF(NOT(C10="SA"), IF(OR(H10=L1,H10=L2), IF(I10="A",
    IF(J10="2",CONCAT(c10:k10), "ERROR"), "ERROR"), "ERROR"), "ERROR")
```

In Excel, both `OR` and `NOT` are actual functions, not operators.  `OR` takes two boolean expressions being compared and returns a boolean output.  `NOT` takes a single boolean expression and returns a boolean output.